# Why a public key encryption scheme cannot be considered perfect according to Shannon?

Tags: perfect-secrecy

I'm looking for a proof of this theorem

Comment: Just think about an attack. It can be terribly costly and have negligible success probability. However, if you find such an attack that proves that the scheme is not information-theoretically secure. If you can figure out a generic attack that works for all PKE schemes you are done.

Comment: PKE schemes are not uncoditionally (or perfectly, or theoretically, or whatever you prefer) secure accroding to Shannon's Theorem. I'm looking for a formal proof

Comment: Do you know of a formal proof of Shannon's theorem? (You can find that anywhere with 3s of research, it's probably on Wikipedia). A formal proof of this theorem will in particular be a formal proof that no PKE scheme is unconditionnally secure.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau 3 seconds? I've found it in just 2.. when I was looking for that. I'm interested in another theorem but luckly someone has understood me

Comment: You are interested in "another theorem"? You explicitly stated that you are looking for a proof that no PKE can be unconditionally secure. Which is exactly an immediate corollary of Shannon's theorem about perfect secrecy (Cédric essentially re-proved Shannon's theorem for the specific case of public-key encryption in his (good) answer below). It seems to me that you were looking for an explanation of Shannon's theorem in the specific case of PKE, not for a formal proof of Shannon's theorem - or are we not talking about the same theorem of Shannon? Anyway, if you got your answer, it's fine :)

Comment: Of course it is fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will just turn [@mephisto's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60507/why-a-public-key-encryption-scheme-cannot-be-considered-perfect-according-to-sha#comment132863_60507) into a longer answer.

The following attack will work against any public-key encryption scheme:

- The attacker has access to the public key and, say, a ciphertext encrypting some unknown message
- for every possible secret key (by enumerating the key space), the attacker does the following:

  - checking whether the secret key does correspond to the known public key (for instance, by encrypting every single possible message then trying to decrypt them using this secret key)
  - when a secret key was found that passed the test of the previous step, the attacker uses it to decrypt the message

Of course this attack will take a gigantic amount of resources, but it will work against any PKE. Now this goes against the idea of *perfect secrecy* which says that getting a ciphertext gives no information about the plaintext, **even for an adversary with unbounded resources**.

Note how such attack will not work against the one-time-pad:
an adversary attacking a one-time-pad only gets a ciphertext, there is no public key. If the adversary picks a random key, betting that it is the key that was used for encryption, it has no way to tell whether it was right or wrong in picking this key.

Comment: No, now he did your homework :-P

Comment: Of course he did. Now go back and do yours :)